# Stata Replacing Part of String

Tags: string, stata

I have 10 digit long string  "0000000000" called `my_var`. I have two variables `highclass` (between 0 and 10) and `lowclass` (between 0 and 10).

I need to convert the digits between `highclass` and `lowclass` to 1.

For example, if a row has `highclass` =5 and `lowclass` =1, then `my_var` should become 1111100000.

I am not sure if the substring command will help me since I need to reference a variable.

Comment: Variable names can't contain spaces; they can contain underscores. I've edited variants on `highclass` and `lowclass` to the same name. If I guessed wrong, you will need to change your code.

Comment: Good questions give reproducible data examples and show explicit attempts at code.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, `lowclass` is the position of the first `1` and `highclass` is the position of the last `1`.

No loops are needed. In fact, a single statement would do it in Stata (which is the language the question is about).

Two ways to do it:

**Old style (particularly pertinent to Stata 12 and below)**

Here I have split the single statement into several, because I suspect it is clearer that way. Note that `substr()` (not `substring()`) is a function, not a command.

```
clear 
input str10 my_var lowclass highclass 
"0000000000"  1  5
"0000000000"  2  4
"0000000000"  3  3 
"0000000000"  1  10
"0000000000"  7  10 
end 

local zeros "0000000000"
local ones  "1111111111" 
replace my_var = substr("`zeros'", 1, lowclass - 1)
replace my_var = my_var + substr("`ones'", 1, highclass - lowclass + 1) 
replace my_var = my_var + substr("`zeros'", 1, 10 - highclass) 

list 

     +----------------------------------+
     |     my_var   lowclass   highcl~s |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 1111100000          1          5 |
  2. | 0111000000          2          4 |
  3. | 0010000000          3          3 |
  4. | 1111111111          1         10 |
  5. | 0000001111          7         10 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

**New style (Stata 13 up)**

Mata and Stata 13 up allow string multiplication, (e.g. `10 * "1"`) so this works:

```
replace my_var = (lowclass - 1) * "0" + (highclass - lowclass + 1) * "1" + (10 - highclass) * "0"
```

Note that e.g. `-1 * "0"` is perfectly legal but evaluates as missing (empty string).